# Installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I experience frequent freezes and crashes (when using NVIDIA graphics card)

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I have been using an old Windows desktop (Asus motherboard, i5 CPU, 120 GB SSD, about 8 years old) to run my Home Assistant server without issues for a few months. I decided I wanted to switch to Ubuntu so that I could run an Ad Guard DHCP server.

I first installed Ubuntu 22.04 along side Windows. I would continuously run into freezing after using Ubuntu for a maximum of 5 minutes. It would often happen when I open a folder or sometimes it would happen without me even touching the mouse. The screen would stay on and sometimes it would display a distorted error message or no error message at all. If there was an error message, it would say "Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error. If you notice further problem, try restarting the computer." The screen would stop changing completely and all inputs were unresponsive.

I concluded that this must be an issue with my dual boot set up with Windows, especially since I had only allocated 25GB to Ubuntu. So I re-installed Ubuntu (same version) but this time I got rid of the windows partition. I am still experiencing the same freezing issue.

I have tried running sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade. /var/crash is completely empty. I have tried running memtest86 (no errors found after several passes). I have used Gnome disk utility SMART self test to check the health of my SSD. The result was that the SSD is fine. I'm now wondering could it be an issue with my motherboard?

The weird part for me is that Windows was working just fine but Ubuntu can't run 5 minutes without crashing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the newest kernel?

Comment: @apkg When I run 'uname -r' I get "5.15.0-37-generic." Since this is a fresh install of the newest Ubuntu release .ISO file wouldn't it come with the newest kernel? Sorry, I'm not super knowledgeable when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: Review your logs (/var/log) and crash files (/var/crash). Look for log files that include  "ERROR:" lines  and similar obvious problems. Simply look at the filenames of the crash files -- that will tell you what application crashed. Between those sources, look for patterns. Some folks misread SMART results; one recent fellow thought "end-to-end:FAIL" meant the disk was fine (it was dying). Keep in mind that a few bad blocks on your SSD in just the right place can make your system hopeless without affecting the other OS at all. That's just one possible cause; there are many.

Comment: @user535733 thank you for your response. I'll take a look at /var/log. /var/crash is empty. I believe I recall the SMART results saying it was functioning well but I'll double check to make sure I'm not misreading it. I had the same thought, a bad block could certainly be the issue and especially given how cheap SSDs are now that would be a fairly easy fix.

Comment: Uh-oh. If /var/crash is empty, that means your system isn't crashing due to known software causes. In other words, higher probability of a hardware fault, not a software bug.

Comment: @user535733 I thought so too but I wasn't sure what the hardware issue was (SSD, motherboard, etc). On another note, I switched my graphics driver to the NVIDIA proprietary driver instead of the open source one, as someone in another post suggested, and I've made it a whole twenty minutes without crashing. We'll see if it lasts. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that the open source GPU driver for my NVIDIA graphics card was the issue. Switching to the proprietary one fixed it.

Comment: I had similar problems in the earlier release.  They came back when 22.04 installed nouveau in place of nvidia, but trying to install nvidia again messed up my system restart.  I hacked away at in in the command line and synaptics, but I may have to reinstall the OS to get it to boot not in recovery.

Comment: How did you install it?  I got burnt with the 340 run file not successfully making a kernel.  nvidia does not show on additional drivers.

Comment: For me, going to "Additional Drivers" and installing the recommend driver fixed the issue :)

Comment: How did you fix it if you can't get in inside

Answer (score 2):

**Solution that worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:**

At login screen in bottom right corner press the little gear icon, and select Ubuntu on Xorg instead of just Ubuntu ( i think Wayland window manager is used there by default ).

**Useful link:**
https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

I came to this solution because i did use secondary SSD to store the games, but even after i unmounted it, freezing happen again, so i excluded SSD as source of problem. And later on by reading online since many users complain about the Wayland issues i decided to give xorg a try and so far so good :)
Also i would like to mention that my Ubuntu system is now much more responsive.

It bugged me quite a while and i decided to post this here in hope that it might help someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

- Update 25 Jan. 2023: Ubuntu kept undoing my manual driver installation when it would run automatic updates (see my notes at the end of Option 2 below), so my final configuration is this: choose the latest-possible-version non-open-kernel NVIDIA driver version provided by Ubuntu which works properly, makes external monitors work, and still allows you to adjust laptop screen brightness with your function keys. For me, that is version **nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary)**. You can see it in the image below in my "Software & Updates" GUI as *"Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary"*:
  [image]
- Update 22 Dec. 2022: I found Option 2 below to be the best (I think...so far).
- Note to self: future thing to try next time first instead of doing everything below:

  See also:

  1. [Can you reverse 'ubuntu-drivers autoinstall'?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1410298/327339)
  2. https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/ - this looks really useful!
  3. [HDMI Port not recognised (NVidia Geforce RTX 3060, Xubuntu 22.04, Dell laptop)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446979/327339)

  ```bash
  # Do NOT run this now if you've already got your drivers working!
  # This is just a note to myself to try this *first* next time is all,
  # and then only try the manual steps below if this doesn't work.
  # - Supposedly this will fix the NVIDIA issue I first experienced on 
  # Ubuntu 22.04 where my external monitor would not work when I 
  # plugged it in.
  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
  reboot
  ```

### How to install the proper NVIDIA graphics driver to hopefully prevent freezes

I'm [trying to follow the OP's accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413753/327339), but don't know which "proprietary one" to use to fix it. I have **8** proprietary driver options to choose from. From the "Software & Updates" --> "Additional Drivers" tab, here is what I am using now (the bottom "X.Org X server" one in the list below--with lots of freezes):

[image]

I plan on choosing the top option in that list to see if that works, then moving my way down the list.

I may also go to NVIDIA's website directly to see if they have any driver downloads I can get straight from them.

[My computer literature](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/bug_reports/issues/3#issuecomment-1352434782) says my graphics card is the "NVIDIA RTX A2000 4GB GDDR6". This seems to coincide with what `lspci` shows, which is good. Notice `lspci` says I have the `NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A2000 Mobile] (rev a1)`:

```bash
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107GLM [RTX A2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2291 (rev a1)
```

### First (required for compatibility with NVIDIA-provided proprietary graphics drivers, probably regardless of which option you do below): enable "Discrete Graphics" in your BIOS/UEFI

Follow the instructions in my answer here: [Enable "Discrete Graphics" in your BIOS/UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446682/327339). NVIDIA's documentation which I cite there and below as well states that disabling "Hybrid"/"Integrated" graphics is required, meaning that you have to choose the "Discrete Graphics" option instead.

Changing the setting from "Hybrid" to "Discrete" graphics is likely required since your computer's manufacturer probably shipped it with the "Hybrid Graphics" option set instead, since hybrid is a little more energy-efficient.

### Option 1: use the first driver in the list in the image above

**Before beginning this option, first enable "Discrete Graphics" in your BIOS/UEFI, as explained above, in order to follow NVIDIA's guidance and be compatible with their drivers.**

So, after choosing the first driver in the "Software & Updates" --> "Additional Drivers" list, the little blurb at the top now says:

> This device is using the recommended driver.

...which is good, instead of:

> This device is using an alternative driver.

Here is the new selection and that text:

[image]

So, "the recommended driver" seems like a good option. :) We'll see how well this one works now.

Update 4 hrs. later: Nope! Bad option! 2 important tips:

1. **Plug in an external monitor and test it any time you change your update your graphics driver!** Some drivers don't support or work with exteranal drivers at all! But, you won't notice at first if you don't test it.
2. **Reboot right after changing your graphics driver, even if not prompted to!** Rebooting ensures you're actually testing your newly-installed driver and not the one you had running before.

So, after I changed to the driver above, it seemed to work fine for 15 minutes or so (because it was actually still running the previous driver), then it randomly spit this image onto my main monitor only, and froze (note: sorry for the horrible quality of the image; I'm uploading a high-quality image and this site keeps horribly compressing it days later):

[image]

When I rebooted, prior to the boot screen even coming up, it also printed these error messages. The "ACPI BIOS Error" was already there, but the last few lines, starting with the line which says "[nvidia_drm]", are all new!:

[image]

And, this new driver *didn't work with an external monitor at all!* The external monitor was blank.

So, I reverted back to the "X.Org X server" driver I had previously in-use above (which freezes sometimes), and *after rebooting*, it was back and my external monitor worked again. Let's go on to Option 2 now.

### (Recommended) Option 2: download and install the driver straight from NVIDIA

**Before beginning this option, first enable "Discrete Graphics" in your BIOS/UEFI, as explained above, in order to follow NVIDIA's guidance and be compatible with their drivers.**

(Here's a quick link to the [NVIDIA "Advanced Driver Search"](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) page, in case you need to rapidly try installing multiple drivers to see which one doesn't break your screen brightness function keys.)

If the above option still has lots of freezes or otherwise doesn't work (ex: [with external monitors as I saw here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1446559/327339)), then you should download the driver straight from the manufacturer, here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us#

Remember, you can find your NVIDIA graphics card version from the output of `lspci` via `lspci | grep -i nvidia`, as I show above.

To find the driver for this card, I went to the link above and chose these options. I highlighted the "Product" line which shows "NVIDIA RTX A000 Laptop GPU", which seems to be my card:

[image]

Once I clicked the "Search" button it brought me to this page: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/196723/en-us/:

[image]

Here is the info. for this driver. Notice how new it is (from 28 Nov. 2022 when today is 20 Dec. 2022):

> Linux X64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver
>
> Version:  525.60.11
> Release Date: 2022.11.28
> Operating System: Linux 64-bit
> Language: English (US)
> File Size:  394.72 MB

First, I check to make sure my card is supported. Under the "Supported Products" tabs I search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in my browser and see that `NVIDIA RTX A2000 Laptop GPU` is in the list.

The "Additional Information" has this valuable information and installation help from NVIDIA:

> Note that many Linux distributions provide their own packages of the NVIDIA Linux Graphics Driver in the distribution's native package management format. This may interact better with the rest of your distribution's framework, and you may want to use this rather than NVIDIA's official package.
>
> Also note that SuSE users should read the SuSE NVIDIA Installer [HOWTO](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers) before downloading the driver.
>
> Installation instructions: Once you have downloaded the driver, change to the directory containing the driver package and install the driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.60.11.run`
>
> One of the last installation steps will offer to update your X configuration file. Either accept that offer, edit your X configuration file manually so that the NVIDIA X driver will be used, or run `nvidia-xconfig`
>
> Note that the list of supported GPU products is provided to indicate which GPUs are supported by a particular driver version. Some designs incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available. Hardware designs will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, so please consult with a system's manufacturer to determine whether that particular system is compatible.
>
> See the [README](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.60.11/README/index.html) for more detailed instructions.
>
> For further information please visit our forum, https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148.

See their README or forum above, if needed.

Then, I search the "Release Highlights" tab for the word "bug" to see if this new driver has any relevant bug fixes. Sure enough, they do! Here are some of them that look particularly important:

> - Fixed a bug which caused Dynamic Boost to not engage on certain AmpereGPU based notebooks.
> - Fixed a bug that resulted in stutter when moving windows in GNOME.
> - Fixed a bug which caused suspend to fail on systems running GNOME 3as a Wayland compositor with NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations enabled.
> - Fixed a bug in the Vulkan driver which could lead to corruption ingeometry and tessellation control shaders.

etc.

**Anyway, this manufacturer-provided driver looks corrrect and useful, so let's try it!**

Click "Download" --> "Agree & Download". It's a pretty large file, at 414 MB.

##### Install the driver:

For any NVIDIA installation help, reference their readme here: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.60.11/README/installdriver.html.

1. First, we must disable the Nouveau open-source reverse-engineered GPU driver in order to continue. Read more about that here if you need background info. or to do additional debugging later: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/525.60.11/README/commonproblems.html#nouveau.

   To disable the Nouveau NVIDIA driver, follow these instructions here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux:

   ```bash
   # create the file to disable Nouveau
   sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
   sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"

   # Verify its contents
   cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
   # It should now contain this:
   #       blacklist nouveau
   #       options nouveau modeset=0

   # Update the kernel initramfs file system. 
   # Don't quote me on this, but I *think* this is a RAM-loaded file system
   # which helps the system boot.
   sudo update-initramfs -u

   # reboot
   reboot
   ```
2. Enable the grub boot menu, if needed, as a tool to let you boot into the command-line with*out* loading graphics drivers first.

   See: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/327339). In short:

   ```bash
   # edit the grub file
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Comment out `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` by adding a `#` at the beginning of that line. Then change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5` to give it a 5 second delay before automatically loading the OS. Then:

   ```bash
   # apply the grub changes
   sudo update-grub

   # reboot to the grub menu
   reboot
   ```
3. Now, you can *not* be graphically logged in, since we are about to update the graphics drivers. So, at the Grub screen, shown here, choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu":

   [image]

   Next, choose the "recovery mode" option, as shown here:

   [image]

   It will begin printing a bunch of boot-up text to the screen, and if your partition is LUKS-encrypted, it will ask you to type in your password:

   > Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... Please unlock disk nvme0n1p5_crypt: _

   Type in your encryption password, if applicable.

   On the "Recovery Menu" screen, choose the "root" option to "Drop to root shell prompt":

   [image]

   It will say:

   > Press Enter for maintenance
   > (or press Control-D to continue): _

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the command prompt as root. You'll now see a prompt like this:

   > `root@my_computer_name:~#`

   You're ready to go! Just keep in mind that when `cd`ing into a directory, `~` will *not* get you to your user's home directory, since you're logged in as `root`, not as your user. Getting to your user's home directory will look like this:

   ```bash
   cd /home/username
   ```
4. (Optional, I think, but I did this anyway) Install some 32-bit compatibility libraries:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install pkg-config
   # Install cmd source: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libglvnd-dev
   sudo apt install libglvnd-dev
   ```
5. Start the installer.

   ```bash
   # cd to where you saved it; ex:
   cd /home/my_username/Downloads/Install_Files/NVIDIA
   # start the installer
   sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.60.11.run
   ```

   It will extract the file and run the installer.

   Choose "Continue installation" when prompted, by selecting with the arrow keys and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   It will then say "Building kernel modules" and have a green bar which progresses to 100%.

   If you chose to install the 32-bit compatibility libraries above (I did), then when it says this:

   > Install NVIDIA's 32-bit compatibility libraries?

   Choose "Yes".

   When it says:

   > Would you like to run the `nvidia-xconfig` utility to automatically update your X configuration file so that the NVIDIA X driver will be used when you restart X?"

   Use the arrow keys to move the white selector box, and choose "Yes".

   When it says the installation is complete, choose "Ok".
6. Cool. That was a pain. I'm glad that's over :). Now reboot.

   ```bash
   reboot
   ```
7. Log in and test an external monitor with your setup. Test your screen brightness function keys. Do they work? If yes, great! You're done! If not, follow my instructions here: [Brightness not working after installing NVIDIA driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446675/327339). You'll have to repeatedly download and install the next-oldest NVIDIA driver until you find one which has functioning brightness buttons. In my case, the latest driver at the time of this writing, 525.60.11, did *not* work, but 5.15.86.01 *did*.

   1. Reinstalling the graphics driver is actually really fast and can be done in < 5 minutes now that you know how to do it. Just reboot into the root terminal via the Grub boot menu and install the next NVIDIA driver, as you just did above.
8. DON'T LET UBUNTU ACCIDENTALLY AUTO-UPDATE YOUR NVIDIA GRAPHICS DRIVER IN THE FUTURE: in the future, when running Ubuntu's automatic updates, read carefully and uncheck any options to install or update NVIDIA graphics drivers. Apparently I wasn't paying attention, and I accidentally allowed it to auto-install some Ubuntu-provided NVIDIA graphics driver, ruining my ability to have an external monitor and control my screen brightness again, so I just had to re-install version 5.15.86.01 manually again, minutes ago (on 8 Jan. 2023). I didn't notice the change until I rebooted and my external monitor didn't work, my screen brightness was at 100% (too bright), and I was unable to decrease it using my <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>BrightnessDown</kbd> button. That was annoying. So, watch out for that. If anyone knows how to block Ubuntu's automatic updates from trying to upgrade the graphics driver automatically after doing a manual NVIDIA install, let me know please.

   Update 18 Jan. 2023: it did it again. :( I just rebooted and my driver was mysteriously changed. Since I had manually installed the 5.15.86.01 driver which worked perfectly, this time I chose the 5.15 option provided by Ubuntu, and rebooted, and it seems to work just fine as well, including allowing me to adjust my screen brightness using my laptop's function keys. Here's the option I just chose:

   [image]

   It's flipping annoying that my manually-installed driver keeps getting changed by Ubuntu, so I'll try to investigate that further to make it stop. Meanwhile, the 5.15 version provided by Ubuntu (same version as what I manually installed) works just fine.

   Here is my follow-up question about this: [Ubuntu keeps undoing my manually-installed NVIDIA graphics driver after reboots every couple weeks](https://askubuntu.com/q/1450864/327339)

### Last tip for a smoother-running experience, in particular when typing in Chrome, *use the X11 window server instead of Wayland!*

X11 is a surprisingly much faster and much better experience, especially in Chrome.

Wayland seems to be more buggy and glitchy and slow. I especially notice it when typing in Chrome, such as when editing this answer right now in Ask Ubuntu. X11 works much smoother, whereas Wayland is jerky and feels a bit unresponsive, again, even while typing this.

To use X11, when you reboot and get to the login screen (assuming your computer doesn't automatically log in for you), ***after you type in or select your username only*, there will be a little gear icon in the bottom-right of the login screen. Click it and select the "Ubuntu" option rather than Ubuntu 22.04's default "Ubuntu with Wayalnd" option.** The "Ubuntu" option runs the traditional X11 window manager server, whereas the "Ubuntu with Wayland" option runs the newer (and glitchier, in my experience) Wayland window manager server.

### Note to self: other things to look into in the future

1. See also my new notes about `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` at the very top of this answer.
2. Which display manager (dm) to use?

   1. [Google search for "lightdm vs gdm3"](https://www.google.com/search?q=lightdm+vs+gdm3&oq=light&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i61j69i65l3j69i61l2.5134j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
   2. https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/gdm3-vs-lightd
   3. [Is gdm3 preferred to lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1004461/327339)

Comment: Many thanks for these detailed instructions. They helped me get my own system working, as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446590/hdmi-port-not-recognised-nvidia-geforce-rtx-3060-xubuntu-22-04-dell-laptop/1446979#1446979

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped solve my problems.
ubuntu 20.04 worked fine, update it to ubuntu 22.04 and got 2 or 3 freezes a day
with no errors in the logs. There can be many causes for this...this is just my issue solution.

What was happening is my nvme drive was turning off.
You can test to see if you have the same issue as I did very easily
When it freezes hit alt + print screen and while holding those keys
type reiusb when you hit b it will reboot and you should see your pc logo if it just sticks on the pc logo and eventually takes you to bios and your storage drive is gone and you have to hit power off to get it to boot back up then you have my issue.
Add this to /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"
sudo update-grub
reboot
Solved my issues