# Ubuntu keeps undoing my manually-installed NVIDIA graphics driver after reboots every couple weeks

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics, update-manager

Goal: lock down my manually-installed video driver so Ubuntu quits undoing it.

Every week or two I reboot my laptop, and each time I do, my manually-installed NVIDIA version 5.15.86.01 graphics driver gets changed, causing my external monitor to no longer work! What's the problem? How do I keep automatic updates or whatever is happening from altering my manually-installed video driver?

To manually install 5.15.86.01, I had followed [my meticulously-detailed instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446523/327339). Under the section titled **"(Recommended) Option 2: download and install the driver straight from NVIDIA"**, see the **"Install the driver"** section.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 if that matters.

---

A few screenshots:

[image]

My currently-selected driver which I just chose after this last time of the manually-installed one getting undone by Ubuntu after my last reboot:

[image]

This driver seems to work okay since its version matches the manually-installed one I had previously installed. 5.15 works. 5.25 with the open kernel does not--it fails to work with external monitors (nothing displays), and it puts the laptop screen at full brightness and won't let me dim the screen.

Comment: @Terrance, I have the NVIDIA RTX A2000 4GB GDDR6, [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhejO.jpg). It's in the list. The 5.25 has a regression bug where it breaks the brightness control. I know it's long, but [my meticulously-detailed instructions go through all that](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446523/327339). The crux of this question though is: how do I make Ubuntu _stop_ messing with my graphics drivers _after_ I've manually installed one?

Comment: Sorry, removed that other comment after I saw that you had the A2000.  You would need to somehow convert the manually installed driver to DKMS so that it will carry over into newer Kernel updates.  NVIDIA claims on their site that their drivers should do it if they detect DKMS installed, but I have not had any luck with those so I have stuck with the drivers from the Ubuntu repos instead.  https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/415.13/README/installdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer; it's a lame work-around:

> I chose the 5.15 option provided by Ubuntu, and rebooted, and it seems to work just fine

From my answer here: [Installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I experience frequent freezes and crashes (when using NVIDIA graphics card)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446523/327339)